# regex for html attributes, need fix

Tags: php, html, regex, extract

Need to fix this regex which extract html attributes in array for me by preg_mach_all function in php:

`(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?`

the attributes example is:

```
style="width: 462px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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.......=" data-filename="Screenshot from 2016-02-09 21:54:47.png"
```

working example in finddle: https://regex101.com/r/QE9XGD/1

because of equals sign in the end of `src` attribute, I got wrong array:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => style="width: 462px;"
            [1] => src="data:image/png;base64,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.......=" data-filename="
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => style
            [1] => src="data:image/png;base64,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.......
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => width: 462px;
            [1] =>  data-filename=
        )

)
```

correct array should be like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => style="width: 462px;"
                [1] => src="data:image/png;base64,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.......="
               [2] => data-filename="Screenshot from 2016-02-09 1:54:47.png"
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => style
                [1] => src
                [2] => data-filename
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => width: 462px;
                [1] => data:image/png;base64,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.......=
                [2] => Screenshot from 2016-02-09 1:54:47.png
            )

    )
```

how to fix this regex to get correct answer?

Remember I use this regex not just in image attributes extraction, is a universal regex for all type of html tags

Comment: And what about a `DOM` way instead???

Comment: Regex is faster, so want regex solution if it is possible

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`(\S+?)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?`

The change is to make the attribute name evaluation *lazy*, so it only eats until it finds an `=`.

Working example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QE9XGD/2)

That being said, I'm fairly confident this regex can be reduced.

---

`([^\s=]+)=('?)("?)([^>"']*)\2\3` is probably the best option:

It takes about 2% of the time of lazy evaluation and will do both singly and doubly quoted attributes. The big change here is the capture groups you want are the 1st and 4th. As far as I'm aware this will work on any html **except**: `tag='"value'`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QE9XGD/9)

Comment: I'm struggling to get the correct regex and one moment I thought that yours was perhaps my chance to get it right. But unfortunately, it doesn't work with `title="What about simple quotes like ' in my title attribute?"`. You also have to add optional spaces around the `=` as `class = stupid-spaces` is valid HTML just like `data-something = 'also stupid spaces'`. I currently have this regex: `\b(?<attr>\w+)\s*=\s*(?<delim>["']|\b)(?<value>.*?)\k<delim>`. But it doesn't work without quoted values and I can't find out a solution :-(